# How can i get dates Saturday to Friday using SQL getdate()

Tags: sql-server

How can I get use gatedate() to always pick up the last Saturday to current Friday.
When I try to use the code I getting a static Saturday date

I have tried this way

```sql
Select 
cast dateadd(y,datediff(y,0,getdate()),-1 ) as date) as Satuday,
cast(dateadd(d,-3,dateadd(week,datediff( week,0,getdate()),0)) as Friday
```

example
Saturday date = 31/12/2023
Friday date = 6/01/2022

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please only tag the (R)DBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The latest version of SQL Server has a handy new function, `DATE_BUCKET` for such tasks.

Comment: I am using version 15 thank you

Comment: I'd suggest investing in a Calendar table then (though i would suggest this any way, they are an invaluable resource), then you can query that table and get the week start and end dates; you *should* have already created one already if I am honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, you can adjust the code...

```
   SELECT DATEADD(DD, 12, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) -1, 0)) -- Saturday
    SELECT DATEADD(DD, 18, DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, DATEADD(dd, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) -1, 0)) -- Friday
```